# How to call function automatically from HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <(some tag #1) ................>
    <(some tag #2) ................>
    <(some tag #3) functionNameToBeCalled(params....)  >
</body>
</html>
```

When the tag # 1&2 are executed and code is on tag #3 I want it to call the function present in the javascript AUTOMATICALLY and NOT by using onclick().

Is there a way to execute this?

Comment: why can't you call the function normally from a script? why is there a need to call it directly from that tag?

Comment: I am iterating values over list to fill table by rows respectively. I am getting 1/0 from backend as one of the value and I want to toggle switch button as per 0/1. And the value I am getting is in one of the tag. Hence, if I get it in tag, I can pass the value to one of the function and set the toggle switch

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski

Comment: Can't you add a listener to that tag?

Comment: @ThRnk How to use that? I am new to the concept.

Comment: if you are using a script to fill the table, why not trigger the function there?

Comment: @ThRnk Listner are similar to OnClick which I dont want to use

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski How can we trigger the function there?

Comment: No idea, you would need to post the code generating the table

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function without a click by using the ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    functionNameToBeCalled(params....)
});
```

Or another vanilla way,

```
<script>
// self executing function here
(function() {
   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here

})();
</script>
```

Also,

There is a standards based replacement,DOMContentLoaded that is supported by over 98% of browsers, though not IE8:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to call function on loading the page but when it is executing particular tag, that time I want it to transfer the elements to a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery delay() method to call a function after waiting for some time. Simply pass an integer value to this function to set the time interval for the delay in milliseconds.

Let's check out an example to understand how this method basically works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Execute a Function after Certain Time</title>
<style>
    img{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showImage(){
    $("img").fadeIn(500);
}
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".show-image").click(function(){
        $(this).text('loading...').delay(1000).queue(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            showImage(); //calling showimage() function
            $(this).dequeue();
        });        
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="show-image">Show Image</button>
    <img src="../images/kites.jpg" alt="Flying Kites">
</body>
</html>
```